# EF 6 Code First Create new Subtype from Supetype

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following data structure:

```
class Person
{
     public int PersonId {get; set}
     public string Name {get; set;}
     public string FieldWithUniqueConstraint {get; set}
}

class Student : Person
{
     public string StudentNumber {get; set;}
}

class Teacher : Person
{
     public string EmployeeNumber {get; set;}
}
```

I am using TPT Hierarchy in EF6, so the above entities exist as 3 tables in SQL Server.

Creating new Students and Teachers work fine, but now a Teacher needs to also be a Student.

If I manually create a new record for a Student Subtype in the database using an existing PersonId, there is no complaint from SQL Server. I get as far as fetching the Student/Teacher from the database using `db.Students/Teachers.SingleOrDefault(e => e.PersonId == personId);`

But how on earth do I use an existing Teacher to create a new Student? Simply doing `db.Students.Add()` does not work due to Primary Key Violation, and I understand why.

If I do manage to get one created, how would you go about deleting only one type?

The trick comes in that the property `FieldWithUniqueContraint` must be present in the structure, otherwise the solution would be easy, just create another record, but Person record must be shared by both Subtypes.

Any insight to this problem will be appreciated.

Comment: This isn't just an EF problem. It's a problem in your class hierarchy. A person can't be both a teacher and a student in your class hierarchy.

Comment: That requires a completely different class design. Inheritance represents an *is a* relationship (and an object can only *be* one type). What you need is a *has a* relationship, for example one `Person ` has a student role and a teacher role.

Comment: @GertArnold, yes, a has a relationship would work better here and it was the first thing I looked at, but due to this already being in production with 1000s of records, changing the structure now is not an option

Comment: @HansKilian Please could you elaborate, I am not understanding you correctly, I think. after manually updating records, can get both the Student and Teacher using 'await db.Student/Teacher.SingleOrDefaultAsync(l => l.PersonId == id)'

I definitely wont be able to say Person p = db.Students... etc

Comment: *changing the structure now is not an option* Then you have to settle with data duplication occurring as of now (2 `Persons` de facto being the same person) which is *much* harder to fix later. I'd say, bite the bullet now and fix it.

Comment: @GertArnold, yeah, cannot even make duplicate records due to the FieldWithUniqueContraint. The temporary solution was to use a different value for the field. But you are right, will probably have to make the structure change sometime.

Comment: With your class hierarchy, the same person can not be a Student and a Teacher at the same time. There is no class that contains both StudentNumber and EmployeeNumber. You say that a Teacher needs to be a Student now. There's no way to do that with the classes you have.

Comment: @HansKilian ah. I see what you are saying and I have never thought of it in that way. I always reasoned that if you have a record for both subtypes, that that would be sufficient to describe them as being both. But this way they are technically 2 different things, that just happen to  have the same primary key (if I am following correctly). So actually then having it like this would be a flaw in data integrity?

Comment: That's right. You can maybe force the data into the tables, but it won't match the classes.

Comment: Thats what I ended up doing, executing a simple insert statement. Will post my aswer later, but it feels like a hack

Answer (score 0):

The 'correct' way for me to resolve this would be to simplify my structure into one table (similar to TPH, but without a discriminator) and assigning roles to the Person as @GertArnold suggested in the comments of the question (see below):

```
class Person
{
     public int PersonId {get; set}
     public string Name {get; set;}
     public string StudentNumber {get; set;}
     public string FieldWithUniqueConstraint {get; set}
     public string EmployeeNumber {get; set;}
     public virtual ICollection<PersonRole> PersonRoles {get; set}  
}

class PersonRole
{
     public in PersonRoleId {get; set;}
     public ICollection<Person> People {get; set;}
     public string RoleName {get; set;}
}
```

But due to time constraints and live data that needs to be merged from multiple tables into one, I had to settle for a quick and dirty solution. In our scenario it is a rare occurrence (1 in 10 000) that a Student/Teacher also needs to be a Teacher/Student, so we ended up 'manually' creating a record in the required subtype:

```
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("INSERT INTO Learner (PersonId, StudentNumber) VALUES (@PersonId, @StudentNumber)",
                    new SqlParameter("@PersonId", id),
                    new SqlParameter("@StudentNumber", "The Student's Number"));
```

It feels a bit like a 'hack' to me, but for now, this will suffice. Comments welcome.